# How to different cell size for all the cells in UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I need to show the images in UICollectioview like  [link](http://www.vancleefarpels.com/ww/en/search/search.html?srchTags=SUB_VINTAGE_ALHAMBRA~).

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To represent items in a grid, you can use [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html).

But it won't work as expected with that large item that takes 2 rows.If you would like to have exactly the same layout, you should implement the `UICollectionViewLayout` [subclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a repo named [Waterfall Layout](https://github.com/ecerney/CollectionViewWaterfallLayout), then use this function:

```
func collectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this help.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nhbalancedflowlayout

This is a open source project named as **NHBalancedFlowLayout** in Objective-c.

In this they have customized the **UICollectionViewLayout** for displaying items of different sizes in a grid.